# What disadvantages of using Application's context instead of Activity's for getting strings?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-context

I need to get String from resources in some place where `Context` object not available. I can pass context object as parameter and get string from resources like this:

```
context.getString(R.string.some_string);
```

But i also can use My `Application (extends Application)` instance like this:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getString(R.string.some_string)
```

Are there any disadvantages for second approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ApplicationContext` when you want to make something global to all activities or to keep hold on something until user go out of your application.

`Activity context` hold on to objects as long as `activity` is `alive` and memory will be released `ondestroy` call of activity but if you have used application context then the object will stay inside memory, as long as your app is active and this can cause a `memory leak`.

In your case , it better to use activity context whenever possible for objects local to that activity specially when something is related with GUI components of activity.

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) for more detail